# Jquery drag drop how to

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

When I drag the div into the droppable div, it should create a new div into the droppable div on the mouse position.

http://jsfiddle.net/thilagajothi/QbBAg/4/

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.drag')
    .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
        return $( this ).clone()
            .css("opacity", .75 )
            .appendTo( this.parentNode );
    } )
    .drag(function( ev, dd ){
        $( dd.proxy ).css({
            top: dd.offsetY,
            left: dd.offsetX
        } );
    })
    .drag("end",function( ev, dd ){
        $( dd.proxy ).remove();
    });
$('.drop').drop(function( ev, dd ){
    $( this ).toggleClass('dropped');
} );
} );
```

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel. See http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: you remove it...and don't append it to new container

Comment: Hello charlirftl still the link is there . Thanks for your time